# Combine 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1

```
     ID     
    --------
    user1     
    --------
    user2    
    --------
    user3   
    --------
    user4    
    --------
```

Table 2

```
 ID    |  Password 
------------------
user1  |   xyz
```

in oracle sql, how can i get the output like this ?

Output

```
 ID    |  Password 
------------------
user1  |   xyz 
-------------------
user2  |  NotAvailable
 ------------------
user3  |  NotAvailable
 ------------------
user4  |  NotAvailable
 ------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Left join.

```
select t1.id,
    coalesce(t2.password, 'NotAvailable') as password
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use outer joins:

```
SELECT t1.id, NVL(t2.password,'NotAvailable')
  FROM t1, t2
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.id, 
   case when table2.password is null then 'NotAvailable'
                                     else table2.password 
   end "Password" 
from table1 
left outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id;
```